# Custom LIKE statement in Java Spring Data and Cassandra @Query

Tags: cassandra, cql

I need to query from a table using LIKE statement where parameters are optional.

**This is custom query where I can filter *employee* table by which Non-Empty request param:**

> Select select = QueryBuilder.select().from("employee");
> Where selectWhere = select.where();
>
> if (!email.isEmpty()) {
> selectWhere.and(QueryBuilder.like("email", "%" + email + "%"));
> }
> if (!firstName.isEmpty()) {
> selectWhere.and(QueryBuilder.like("first_name", "%" + firstName + "%"));
> }
> *//Note: User will provide either email or first_name or both.*

However, the above custom query will need to manually map the Rows to the object which I find too tedious:

> ResultSet rs = cassandraClient.getApplicationSession().execute( select );
> return rs.all().stream().map(row -> row.getString("first_name")).collect( Collectors.toList() );

**Is there a way where I can use a Query annotation like below, so it will return the entity directly?**
*@Query("SELECT * FROM employee WHERE email LIKE :email AND first_name LIKE :firstName")* 
Employee search(@Param(value="email" String email, @Param(value="firstName" String firstName)

I tried passing an empty parameter value, but I am getting the following error:

> LIKE value can't be empty.

Comment: I don't mean to "buzzkill" here, but building a dynamic query interface to filter on arbitrary columns in Cassandra using `ALLOW FILTERING` and `LIKE` sounds like a really terrible idea.

Comment: @aaron Thank you for pointing out the 'allow filtering'. I will remove it from my question. My concern is for the LIKE. Please advise on that.